# Read -s with timeout shows text after timeout

Tags: bash, ubuntu, dd-wrt

Hello I'm using read in bash to ask for a password and have -s to hide input and -t 10 to timeout and all works as expected except for one thing.
Here is the code (I'm using the array switch):

```
read -t 10 -a mp -s -p "Enter Password:"
```

It hides the input and if I don't type anything it returns to prompt in 10 secs.
But if I type first 10 chars of a 12 char pass and it times out well when it returns it shows the chars I typed on the next line.

Example:

```
DD-WRT-Bash:~# read -t 10 -a mp -s -p "Enter Password:"
```

(i type testing123)

If I don't hit enter and it times out next line is:

```
DD-WRT-Bash:~# testing123
```

It does the same thing in Ubuntu.
Is there anyway to prevent the text from being returned on the next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using the `-N` option in order to circumvent `read`'s behaviour that is to only consume full lines of input.

The description of `-N` starts as follows :

> -N nchars
> read returns  after  reading  exactly  nchars  characters
> rather  than waiting for a complete line of input, unless
> EOF is encountered or read times out.

Using a value large enough that your users wouldn't be able to reach it before the timeout seems to work well :

```
read -t 10 -a mp -s -N 9999 -p "Enter Password:"
```

A partial line will be stored into the array and won't be reproduced on your console's next line of input.

Comment: Thank you. That works great. My script works as intended now. Appreciate the fast response.